# Remove specific user from firebase using react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to react native and firebase. I have a users table in my firebase database and I wanna delete a particular user from that table but when I call deleteData() function it removes the whole users table. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

```
deleteData(){
  firebase.database().ref('Users/').remove(Name);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data), to remove data, you need to call `remove()` on a reference to the location of that data. In your case, the reference is "Users", not a single user. Please pass userId to refer to a single user:

```
deleteData() {
  firebase.database().ref('Users/' + userId).remove();
}
```